# I need to parse an xml file using python script but I am unable to fetch and store those particular name which are inside a tag in a variable?

Tags: python-2.7

```html
<MA>
        <ZO>
                <ADD>abc</ADD>
                <SC NAME="Part 1" TYPE="WE" FILEPATH=""/>
                <PE>
                        <WE>1</WE>
                        <WE>53</WE>
                        <WE>abc</WE>
                </PE>
        </ZO>

        <ZO>
                <ADD>abc</ADD>
                <SC NAME="Part 2" TYPE="WE" FILEPATH=""/>
                <PE>
                        <WE>1</WE>
                        <WE>53</WE>
                        <WEE>abc</WEE>
                </PE>
        </ZO>


        <ZO>
                <ADD>abc</ADD>
                <SC NAME="Part 3" TYPE="WE" FILEPATH=""/>
                <PE>
                        <WE>1</WE>
                        <WE>53</WE>
                        <WEE>abc</WEE>
                </PE>
        </ZO>

                <WRITETAG>Written by App</WRITETAG>
</MA>
```

I need to fetch the name under ZO

like:

```
Part 1
Part 2
Part 3
```

Comment: Please click on "Thnaks in advance link" to check the xml file

Comment: Please, post your XML sample on SO and tell us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have posted your requirment. Thanks Laurent

Comment: I was using this code...import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
global SCHEDULE
tree = ET.parse('ma.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for ZO in root.findall('ZO'):
       name = ZO.get('NAME')
        print(name)..I am unable to store this 3 inside a variable

Comment: put what you have tried in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can do your parsing using the famous [lxml](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-parse-function) library.

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse(filename)
```

And then, use [XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) to get the `SC` elements:

```
nodes = tree.xpath("//ZO/SC")
```

Use a simple loop to print the names:

```
for node in nodes:
    print(node.attrib["NAME"])
```

Comment: Thank Laurent ...this one helped me...thanks bro for your support

Comment: Can you help me with one more thing I want to store the extracrted names inside distinct variables so that I can use it later on.